# Why is 256 color display not working with linux console, while it does with screen?

Tags: linux, terminal, python, encoding, ncurses

I am working on a python program with a text-mode GUI based on urwid. urwid is a library to create ncurses-style programs with python.

Operating System is CentOS 7.

Everything works fine under 'normal' conditions (X-Server, terminal window). However, on a linux console without X-Server, urwid switches to a low-color mode. (With wrong color codes on certain machines, I get annoyingly blinking text than)

The funny point is, still using linux console, I just need to start screen as a workaround. Inside screen everything is fine again. Without having any special configuration for screen.

I already tried to compare a lot of environment information between pure text shell and screen shell, but that didn't help. For example, locale is identical, pythons  sys.stdout.encoding is the same, doing ":runtime syntax/colortest.vim" in vim looks correct and colorful in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. It happens simply because the Linux kernel console *does not support* the 256-color mode. It wasn't written to use 256 colors, as in [VGA text mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode) there's simply no way to do that. (In framebuffer mode it could, but the code still has the exact same constraints.) GNU Screen knows this and automatically translates from the 256-color palette to the nearest 16-color one.

Only very recent Linux versions (3.13 and later) [started *recognizing*](https://git.kernel.org/linus/3415097ff0529eac264b8ccfa06572871e45c090) the 256-color escape codes, but even then it still maps them to the 16-color palette just like Screen would.

There are framebuffer-based terminal emulators like *kmscon* or *fbterm* which implement their own rendering, and draw everything via KMS. Use those if you want a capable terminal avoiding X11.

---

Blinking text happens because the 256-color codes are very easily confused the 16-color ones. For example, `ESC [38;5;35m` can be interpreted as the 256-color code, or three ANSI (16-color) codes.

- The Linux console doesn't know what `38` means, so it just interprets `5` as "enable blink" and `35` as "foreground – color #5 (magenta)" in the usual way. 
   *(See for example [this table](http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html), under "SGR".)*
- Meanwhile, your X11 terminals recognize the `38` as the magic "foreground – extra colors" code, so they interpret `5` as "use 256-color palette" and `35` as "use color #35 (cyan)". 
   *(There's a 24-bit RGB mode too, as `ESC [38;2;<r>;<g>;<b>m`.)*